# How can I combine two patterns in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to merge these 2 regexp in one
`next if $line =~ /^#/ or $line =~ /^\d+\-\d+/;`

Comment: Lookup alternation and (non capturing) groups.

Answer (score 8):

"or" is easy: use the alternation `|`:

```
next if $line =~ /^#|^\d+-\d+/
```

You can even factor `^` out:

```
/^(?:#|\d+-\d+)/
```

Comment: I'd suggest that OP not combine them, since I think it's clearer to read as two separate patterns. There may be a teeny speedup in combining them, but if OP is reading through a file (as I imagine they are) then the disk IO time will dwarf the regex matching.

Comment: @AndyLester: I agree. The "Why" should have been the first comment on the OP.

Comment: I disagree. Both the combined and the separated versions are perfectly readable. If anything, I prefer the version in the answer. "What are we checking? A pattern match. What pattern? Starts with `#` or a <whatever>" The alternative has more cognitive steps. Its only saving grace is that each of those steps are trivial.